# Variables reset to zero when I call a method

Tags: c#, console-application

I want `choice == 1` to only be able to be selected five times, so I initialized a variable `firstClass = 0`, then set up a do-while for `firstClass < 5`. I included `firstClass++` in my do-while to act as a counter. However, I think firstClass is re-initializing every time I call the method `CheckIn()`. How can I prevent this from happening? Thanks in advance.

```
using System;

namespace Assignment7
{
    class Plane
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the Airline Reservation System.");
            Console.WriteLine("Where would you like to sit?\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Enter 1 for First Class.");
            Console.WriteLine("Enter 2 for Economy.");
            CheckIn();
        }

        public static void CheckIn()
        {
            int choice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int firstClass = 0;
            int economy = 0;

            if (choice == 1)
            {
                do
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You have chosen a First Class seat.");
                    firstClass++;
                    CheckIn();
                } while (firstClass < 5);
            }
            else if (choice == 2)
            {
                do
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You have chosen an Economy seat.");
                    economy++;
                    CheckIn();
                } while (economy < 5);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("That does not compute.");
                CheckIn();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is entirely normal. If you want the variable to exist outside the method, you must *declare* it outside a method, as a "field". Simply move the:

```
int firstClass = 0;
```

outside the method, adding the `static` modifier (in this case):

```
static int firstClass = 0;
```

Note also that this by itself is not thread-safe; if threading is an issue (for example, ASP.NET) then use `int newValue = Interlocked.Increment(ref firstClass);`. I only mention this because *in the general case* `static` data should consider threading, but I suspect it isn't an issue in your case (a console exe).

Answer (score 1):

The firstClass variable is method scoped.  Every time the method is called the variable is reinitialized.  To have firstClass become an ongoing counter it needs to be outside the method, within the class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take any exit condition out of your method and put it outside, either by making a new method or putting it in the one that's calling it already.

For example you could do something like:

```
using System;

namespace Assignment7
{
    class Plane
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the Airline Reservation System.");
            Console.WriteLine("Where would you like to sit?\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Enter 1 for First Class.");
            Console.WriteLine("Enter 2 for Economy.");
            CheckIn(0, 0);
        }

        public static void CheckIn(int firstClassSeatsTaken, int economySeatsTaken)
        {
            int choice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            if (choice == 1)
            {
                do
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You have chosen a First Class seat.");
                    firstClass++;
                    CheckIn(firstClassSeatsTaken, economySeatsTaken);
                } while (firstClass < 5);
            }
            else if (choice == 2)
            {
                do
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You have chosen an Economy seat.");
                    economy++;
                    CheckIn(firstClassSeatsTaken, economySeatsTaken);
                } while (economy < 5);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("That does not compute.");
                CheckIn(firstClassSeatsTaken, economySeatsTaken);
            }
        }
    }
}
```